# Implementing other maps than Google or Mapbox

Tags: nativescript

As in title. Is it possible to implement maps other than Google Maps or Mapbox (they are expensive)? I would aim into Open Street Maps or other free solution as I would like to use it in my commercial app.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use open street maps fine in a NativeScript application.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS & https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Android

You would just need to call into the OSM maps API.  You can check out several blogs from nsbloggers.com as several bloggers have written posts on how to take a native component and make it into a NativeScript plugin.